# facebook, how to get more information concerning the likes?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

i am grabbing the likes of my friends, but i also want to grab the links that are found in that likes.

When you like something the like on your wall will point to something, whatever u liked. I am talking about all those links.

edit:
the response i get right now looks something like:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "name": "Seam Legging - Shooting Star",
     "category": "Product/service",
     "id": "114310318626160",
     "created_time": "2011-06-15T22:26:18+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Junior's 535\u2122 Legging - Seaport Blue",
     "category": "Product/service",
     "id": "146626898728947",
     "created_time": "2011-06-15T22:26:17+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Singer Needed For Pleasure Band CA Music   Vocals Los Angeles, CA auditions Modeling Acting Auditions & Casting Calls ExploreTalent modeling audition america next top model",
     "category": "Website",
     "id": "122740287810745",
     "created_time": "2011-06-15T19:06:13+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Looking for singers R/B Britney type K P Music   Vocals Los Angeles, CA auditions Modeling Acting Auditions & Casting Calls ExploreTalent extras acting extra",
     "category": "Website",
     "id": "130850386995940",
     "created_time": "2011-06-15T19:06:12+0000"
  },......
```

edit2:

i have been trying to use FQL. but i still dont get the links from inside likes:

her is my code so far

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $client_id,
'secret' => $client_secret,
'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$likelink = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT likes FROM stream WHERE source_id ='.$myself.'', ));
print_r($likelink);

?>
```

Comment: can you please show the JSON object returned to you by the API call?

Comment: `{

   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Seam Legging - Shooting Star",
         "category": "Product/service",
         "id": "114310318626160",
         "created_time": "2011-06-15T22:26:18+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Junior's 535\u2122 Legging - Seaport Blue",
         "category": "Product/service",
         "id": "146626898728947",
         "created_time": "2011-06-15T22:26:17+0000"
      }`

Comment: i basically get: `name`, `id`, `category` and the `date created`

Comment: if you go here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and press on the like link you will see.

Comment: I saw it... but the problem is, i can't see any docs that will let me retrieve the links. I guess FQL should come to your resue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After retrieving the list of likes you have, you then need to go through them, get the ID and open up:

https://graph.facebook.com/ID

Which will give you more details regarding that specific item which you liked. For example for the first item in your data:

https://graph.facebook.com/114310318626160

```
{
   "id": "114310318626160",
   "name": "Seam Legging - Shooting Star",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50281_114310318626160_1881220_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://r.levi.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4068748",
   "likes": 115,
   "category": "Product/service",
   "website": "http://r.levi.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4068748",
   "description": "Buy Seam Legging - Shooting Star - Top-stitched seams at the leg give this super-skinny fit just the right amount of detail - and slims its look, too. Its four pockets keep it comfortable."
}
```

And from there, you can probably guess that the `link` is the actual link to the liked item. Do note that not all items liked are some websites, but they can be for example Facebook pages for example:

https://graph.facebook.com/108905269168364

```
{
   "id": "108905269168364",
   "name": "Conan O'Brien Presents: Team Coco",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/211060_108905269168364_696236_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/teamcoco",
   "likes": 1639441,
   "category": "Tv show",
   "website": "www.teamcoco.com\n",
   "username": "teamcoco",
   "description": "Welcome to the official Team Coco Facebook page!  Yes, imagine for a moment, an alternate reality in which Conan O'Brien and his brethren can finally be experienced as they were always meant to be: shoehorned into the madcap blue and white webpage templates of Mr. Mark Zuckerberg!  This is that reality!  Let us live the adventure together, fearless Socialnauts!\n\nWhile this page is \"official\", it's here to be YOUR playground.  Anyone can post here, so go crazy; we only ask that posts remain on-topic.  If you're a purveyor of spam, smut, or unkindness, kindly die -- as you will be banned from this page.  \n\nBy the way, you can also find Conan & Team Coco on other, similarly awesome corners of the internets:\n\nteamcoco.com\ntwitter.com/teamcoco\nteamcoco.tumbler.com\nyoutube.com/teamcoco\nfoursquare.com/teamcoco\nflickr.com/teamcoco\n\nToodles,\n\n- Your Pals \u0040 Team Coco",
   "genre": "Comedy",
   "network": "TBS",
   "checkins": 3
}
```

But in that case, the `link` defines the url to the Facebook page.